# Which permissions are required to implement an LWC record edit form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, permissions, lightning-recordeditform

I'm developing an LWC with a custom record edit form and running into an issue with permissions displaying the form.  I've ruled out field-level permissions being an issue by removing every field on the record edit form and still having the security block.  I've also verified I have record-level CRUD permissions for the object in question.  Are there any other security permissions I can look into?

Failing network call: [https://{sandbox-url}/aura?r=28&aura.RecordUi.getRecordCreateDefaults=1](https://%7Bsandbox-url%7D/aura?r=28&aura.RecordUi.getRecordCreateDefaults=1)

Error ID: 1070765045

[image]

prioritizationWidget.html (truncated)

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="tables.CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TABLE">
  <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
  <h3 class="label slds-truncate slds-p-around_x-small slds-theme_shade">General Information</h3>
  <lightning-input-field class="customerRequestField" field-name="fields.CUSTOMER_FIELD" data-api-name={fields.CUSTOMER_FIELD.fieldApiName} variant="label-stacked" onchange={profileDataHandler} required></lightning-input-field>
  <lightning-input-field class="customerRequestField" field-name="fields.CONTACT_FIELD" data-api-name={fields.CONTACT_FIELD.fieldApiName} variant="label-stacked" onchange={profileDataHandler} required></lightning-input-field>
  <lightning-input-field class="customerRequestField" field-name="fields.STATUS_FIELD" data-api-name={fields.STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName} variant="label-stacked" onchange={profileDataHandler} required></lightning-input-field>
  <h3 class="label slds-truncate slds-p-around_x-small slds-theme_shade">Customer Request Details</h3>
  <lightning-input-field class="customerRequestField" field-name="fields.SUMMARY_FIELD" data-api-name={fields.SUMMARY_FIELD.fieldApiName} variant="label-stacked" onchange={profileDataHandler} required></lightning-input-field>
  <lightning-input-field class="customerRequestField" field-name="fields.DESCRIPTION_FIELD" data-api-name={fields.DESCRIPTION_FIELD.fieldApiName} variant="label-stacked" onchange={profileDataHandler} required></lightning-input-field>
  <lightning-input-field class="customerRequestField" field-name="fields.BUSINESS_NEED_FIELD" data-api-name={fields.BUSINESS_NEED_FIELD.fieldApiName} variant="label-stacked" onchange={profileDataHandler} required></lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

prioritizationWidget.js (truncated)

```
import CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TABLE from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c';
import CUSTOMER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c.Customer__c';
import CONTACT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c.Contact__c';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c.Status__c';
import SUMMARY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c.Summary__c';
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c.Description__c';
import BUSINESS_NEED_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ChangeRequest__c.Business_Need__c';

export default class PrioritizationWidget extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
  @track dragStart;
  @track ElementList = [];
  newCRModalOpen = false;

  tables = {
    CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TABLE
  }

  fields = {
    CUSTOMER_FIELD,
    CONTACT_FIELD,
    STATUS_FIELD,
    SUMMARY_FIELD,
    DESCRIPTION_FIELD,
    BUSINESS_NEED_FIELD
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pasted `.html` is exactly as you have deployed it then I'm thinking your problem may be in how you are setting the `object-api-name` and `field-name` attributes.

Instead of `object-api-name="tables.CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TABLE"` it should be `object-api-name={tables.CUSTOMER_REQUEST_TABLE}` (same change goes for `field-name` in every field).